# I have a problem with my code and I need some advice

Tags: python

my teacher give me a assignment to do and now i really facing the deadend because of my own code, can you guys explain that why in checkqq function the line 'for line in x' doesnt work because when i run , it cannot work the that i expected , here is result that my teacher want and my code

> Choose your solution file: sol1.txt Choose your exam file: exam1.txt
> Student score : [9, 6, 9, 8, 7, 7, 9, 8]
>
> Question 1 : 0.625 Question 2 : 1.0 Question 3 : 0.5 Question 4 :
> 0.875 Question 5 : 0.875 Question 6 : 1.0 Question 7 : 0.75 Question 8 : 0.75 Question 9 : 0.75 Question 10 : 0.75
>
> Hardest : 3 Easiest : 2 6

this last two part i havent work on it yet , 
but i would appreciate your advice about how to do it

```
def check(x,y):
    score=0
    for i,u in zip(x,y) :
        i=i.strip(' ')
        u=u.strip(' ')
        if i==u : 
            score+=1
        else : score=score
    return score
    
def checkqq(y,x,n): #y=sol1.txt and x=exaf
    score=0
    for line in x : #for line in exaf :
        line=line.strip().split() #line=line.strip().split()
        print(line)
        if line[n].strip('')==y[n].strip('') :
            score+=1
    sc=score/8
    b=n+1
    print(f'Question {b} : {sc}')

def run():
    # YOUR CODE HERE
    sol=input( 'Choose your solution file:') 
    exa=input('Choose your exam file:')
    stu=8
    solf=open(sol,'r') 
    exaf=open(exa,'r')
    stusco=[]
    for line in exaf :
        line=line.strip().split()
        for line2 in solf : 
            line2=line2.strip().split()
        a=check(line,line2)
        stusco.append(a)
    for c in range(10) :
        checkqq(line2,exaf,c)
    print(f'Student Score :{stusco}')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193).  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Modify the checkqq function to take a list of lines instead of the file object itself using readlines(). Try something like this for getting the hardest and easiest score; hardest = scores.index(min(scores)) + 1

Comment: How is that the duplicate? The question seems to be about how to calculate the min and max question averages not how to read multiple lines from a file at once.

Comment: @JonSG *"'for line in x' doesnt work"* — If you trace that back, that `x` is the open file from `exaf=open(exa,'r')`, which has already been iterated over once with `for line in exaf`… Or in fact multiple times by `checkqq`, because it's being called in a loop.